# How does one set the RAM and CPU parameters for java programs running in an anaconda environment?

Tags: java, anaconda, picard

In a standard Linux environment with java installed, I can run the any java program using the command:

```
java -jar path/to/picard.jar
```

Where picard is an example of a java program.
I can also specify how many CPU threads or RAM the JVM should use using this way:

```
java -XX:ParallelGCThreads=5 -Xms900m -jar path/to/program.jar
```

That JVM will get 5 threads and and 900 MB of RAM.
All quite straight forward.

However, when I run java programs in an anaconda (conda) environment, which has it's own installation of java, I can run the software simply by typing it:

```
picard
```

How do I pass the resource parameters to anaconda? What are the default parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to first, find where Conda installed Picard within your environment and then give a full path to `picard.jar` while passing memory arguments to `java`:

```
java -Xms4G -jar path_to/picard.jar [your_picard_command]
```

Comment: I actually figured this out by myself, but forgot to add it here. Good job!